# How to list files in an ansible role folder

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I'm struggling to get a list with all files under a subfolder of `templates` role folder using the `find` module, So to use it afterwards and delete all remote files which are not included in my role folder. Here is the task inside my role:

```
    - name: Register local file list before copy to remote
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: templates/services
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: list_files
```

The problem is that the path I use is not detected by ansible so I get errors like this:

```
skipped_paths:
    templates/services: '''templates/services'' is not a directory'
```

So it seems that `find` module is not handling local folders in the same way as `template` module does with its `src` attribute. Any ideas how to refer to a local roles folder? Please note that **it must not be a full path** since the role will be reused from others too.

Thank you community!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a magic variable `role_path` :)

```
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: "{{ role_path }}/templates/services"
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: list_files
```

Comment: If your role is running with `become: true` it would be a good idea to add `become: false` to this step.